# Merge causes too slow, how to optimize this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I optimize this query. I am using merge to pull inserted id's

I have looked at execution plan. It was causing more cost on sort.

Is there any other way to do this instead of using merge. I have tried using BY TARGET. Still its slow. I want to get ride of this merge statement.

```
DECLARE @TEMP_STUDENT_DETAILS_ID AS TABLE (STUDENT_DETAILS_ID INT, SCHOOL_ID INT)

MERGE INTO DBO.STUDENT_DETAILS USING (
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MARKS),0) AS MARKS, SCHOOL_ID
FROM DBO.OLD_STUDENT_DETAILS
WHERE SCHOOL_ID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY SCHOOL_ID) SRC ON 1 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (MARKS
       ,SCHOOL_ID
       ,CODE_ID
       ,CODE_VALUE
       ,CREATED_BY
       ,CREATED_DATE
       ,MODIFIED_BY
       ,MODIFIED_DATE)
VALUES (SRC.MARKS
       ,SRC.SCHOOL_ID
       ,101 --CODE_ID
       ,'ADA' --CODE_VALUE
       ,'Admin'
       ,GETDATE()
       ,'Admin'
       ,GETDATE())
OUTPUT INSERTED.STUDENT_DETAILS_ID, SRC.SCHOOL_ID INTO @TEMP_STUDENT_DETAILS_ID;
```

Comment: What is the point of the merge here anyway? You have it hard coded to never match with the merge predicate. Why not simply use an insert statement???

Comment: @SeanLange Perhaps the idea is to use the OUTPUT clause, but yeah: I'd just INSERT/SELECT.

Comment: Yes to ouput id's i have used merge. Is there any other way to optimize this without merge. I saw at execution plan causes more cost at merge statements and sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OUTPUT statement with an insert. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql This is certainly a bit cleaner than a merge with a forced not matching.

```
INSERT DBO.STUDENT_DETAILS
(   MARKS
    ,SCHOOL_ID
    ,CODE_ID
    ,CODE_VALUE
    ,CREATED_BY
    ,CREATED_DATE
    ,MODIFIED_BY
    ,MODIFIED_DATE
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.STUDENT_DETAILS_ID, INSERTED.SCHOOL_ID INTO @TEMP_STUDENT_DETAILS_ID
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MARKS),0) AS MARKS
    , SCHOOL_ID
    ,101 --CODE_ID
    ,'ADA' --CODE_VALUE
    ,'Admin'
    ,GETDATE()
    ,'Admin'
    ,GETDATE()
FROM DBO.OLD_STUDENT_DETAILS
WHERE SCHOOL_ID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY SCHOOL_ID
```

Comment: I don't see SRC alias

Comment: My bad, it should be INSERTED. I was coding blind here.

Comment: Great!. Thank You

Comment: What if department ID is not in inserting table and still we want to have in our output clause?

Comment: If it isn't being inserted you would have to have to use a hard coded value or a variable.

Comment: But it would be list of department id's , how can i do that if there are list of id's

Comment: Well this is all new since your original question. How could I know what your logic needs to be here? Are you wanting to insert a new row for each departmentID? Are you wanting this as a column in the new table? Without any details I can't possibly help much.

Comment: So something like this which comes from source table `OUTPUT INSERTED.STUDENT_DETAILS_ID, SRC.SCHOOL_ID, SRC.OrganisationId INTO @TEMP_STUDENT_DETAILS_ID;`

Comment: So `SRC.OrganisationId` is not in insert table but it's in select query

Comment: So add SRC.OrganizasationId to the OUTPUT clause. You would need to define that as the alias.

Comment: How is that. Can you please modify it

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to adjust the OUTPUT clause to include one more column? This is really scary to me. Please, try. If I spoon feed you every single piece how are you going to learn anything or support your code??

Comment: Tried with that earlier but since output clause is above select its not taking alias